# TabView with ACtionBar

Tags: google-maps, tabview

I am using tabview in my application, in which Home is default tab selected [image]

I add three `Buttons` over this activity.I want that when i click on `List button` of `MapView Activity`, this
 [image] 
`MapPinsListView Activity` will start on the same frame over `MapView` & rest view will remains same i.e., all tabs will works as they intended to work. However, i am facing a problem while using it, When i click on list, intent will start new activity & hole view get replaced by its activiy view, whereas i want only the frame view will change by the view of called intent & when click on Map button of `MapPinsListView`, `MapView` will start. How should i proceed.

Would appreciate your help a lot!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after having a long R&D i got the best way to do this is

1.code TabGroupActivity which extends ActivityGroup.The purpose of this Activity is to manage the activities in a tab. Note that Child Activities can handle Key Presses before they are seen here.

2.code different classes (e.g., TabGroupHome, TabGroupFavourite, TabGroupMassage & so on...) & extends TabGroupActivity.

3.finally code TabActivity which extends TabActivity & then add these TabGroupActivities(TabGroupHome, Favourite, Massage, Profile, Settings) ovew there respactive tabSpace.

finally, after completing these all different activities get managed over the same fram!
http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html