# ListView having image and two text fields on it

Tags: android, listview

I am working on Activity having ListView & i request an php file from server which returns me one JSONArray having data of all users (e.g, [{"name":"A","ID":"id","img":"X"},{"":"" ...},{"":"" ...}] ). I get it in one JSONArray in my activity and extract JSONObject from it and from this JSONObject i get all values. An ArrayAdapter< String > works well but i wanted to display it in this way -->

1.an imageView having image of user at the left

2.textView having the name of user

3.textView below name having id of user

How I do this?
Would appreciate your help a lot!

Comment: I find this link for http://www.technotalkative.com/android-%E2%80%93-listview-%E2%80%93-5-%E2%80%93-optimized-custom-listview/ read it, hope this solve your problem...

Comment: i get rid out of this problem. It Works! thanks a lot... @Deepak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you will need to create your own custom adapter for your list.

Create a layout that meets your criteria(which will be the row in your list) and then create your on Custom Adapter extending the BaseAdapter class and inflate your view.

Comment: Let me know if you dont know how to do this.

Comment: i get the desired look of my listView, Now my list view have image ,name & id of user. I want that when i click on list item, the complete profile of the respactive user get displayed...? I get data of user from JSONArray containing JSONObject as its data elements where each JSONObject is the data of a unique user. let me tell that what my app is about, its an tabbed based app having 5 tabs. I use ViewGroup to manage multiple activities over the same "fram". screenshot-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244210/tabview-with-actionbar.here onword what i do to show complete profile onItmClk @c

Comment: YOu just need to override onItemClick with your listview you are using. When it is clicked you just load the activity that will show the users profile and just pass the unique user id with it using intent and load the profile